# How should an 8-pin, 3-position slide switch be wired for 1st position off, 2nd position on 1 & 3rd position on 2?

Tags: spdt

I want to make a speaker amp with 2 amplifiers, to select which I would like to use a slide switch with 8 pins and 3 positions and the following functions:

Position 1 - Off

Position 2 - Amp 1

Position 3 - Amp 2

What would be the wiring scheme?

Comment: Can you provide a picture and/or a link to the spec sheet for this switch?

Comment: what should be the state of Amp 1 when the switch in in Position 2? ... your description is incomplete

Answer (score 1):

Here's the switching scheme in a 2P3T slide switch.

[image]

For each pole, the contacts would be as follows:

Position 1 - C & 1

Position 2 - C & 2

Position 3 - C & 3.

For your requirement, you need to skip contact 1 and use only contacts C, 2, & 3 as follows:

[image]

The other pole may also be used should you require 0V also to be switched.